# Do PushSharp support windows phone 8.1 push notification?

Tags: windows-phone-8, pushsharp

In the documentation of PushSharp (Nuget package WP8 is mentioned but not WP8.1. So PushSharp support WP8.1 or not?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft didn't change anything on their Push Notification Service since WP 8,which means you can send push notifications to both WP 8/8.1 in the same way without any differences

In other words,PushSharp supports both WP 8/8.1